# Отправка form-data через CURL

Tags: php, curl, form

Сервер принимает в обработку текстовом формате данные через form-data.
Не могу понять как правильно эти данные отправить ? 
Через [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) всё работает корректно.
При отправке из кода не видит.

```
    <?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "site.ru",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,

  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",

  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\"\r\n\r\ndate_start=28-10-2018&Phone=%2B7(978)054-62-98&Email=webdizaine%40gmail.com&Transport%5BCategory_Nasko%5D=3366&Transport%5BMark_Nasko%5D=371531&Transport%5BModel_Nasko%5D=371591&Transport%5BCategory_Nasko_Name%5D=&Transport%5BMark_Nasko_Name%5D=TOYOTA&Transport%5BModel_Nasko_Name%5D=RAV4&Transport%5BYearIssue%5D=2012&Transport%5BPower%5D=180&Transport%5BMaxMass%5D=0&Transport%5BUnladenMass%5D=0&Transport%5BPasQuant%5D=0&ident_type=vin&Transport%5BVIN%5D=JTMDFREV40D003260&Transport%5BBodyNumber%5D=&Transport%5BChassisNumber%5D=&Transport%5BLicensePlate%5D=%D0%90315%D0%9C%D0%9E186&doc_type=31&DocCarSerial=8655&DocCarNumber=753379&DocumentCarDate=07-09-2017&dk_num=061790041700448&dk_date_to=02-05-2019&neogr=0&Drivers%5B1%5D%5BLastName%5D=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0&Drivers%5B1%5D%5BFirstName%5D=%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F&Drivers%5B1%5D%5BMiddleName%5D=%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0&Drivers%5B1%5D%5BBirthDate%5D=08-02-1986&Drivers%5B1%5D%5BSex%5D=2&Drivers%5B1%5D%5BSeria%5D+req_kbm=8608&Drivers%5B1%5D%5BNumber%5D+req_kbm=961752&Drivers%5B1%5D%5BExperienceDate%5D=20-07-2004&insurant%5BSurname%5D=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD&insurant%5BName%5D=%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD&insurant%5BPatronymic%5D=%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87&insurant%5BBirthDate%5D=01-10-1984&insurant%5BSex%5D=1&insurant%5BSeria%5D=7508&insurant%5BNumber%5D=225428&insurant%5BDate_issue%5D=05-05-2008&insurant%5BIssued%5D=%D0%A3%D0%A4%D0%9C%D0%A1&insurant%5BAddress%5D=%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF+%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC%2C+%D0%B3+%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%2C+%D1%83%D0%BB+%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%2C+%D0%B4+137+&insurant%5BZip%5D=295013&insurant%5BState%5D=%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF+%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC&insurant%5BRegion%5D=&insurant%5BCity%5D=%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C&insurant%5BStreet%5D=%D1%83%D0%BB+%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F&insurant%5BHouse%5D=137&insurant%5BBuilding%5D=&insurant%5BApartment%5D=&insurant%5Bfias_level%5D=8&insurant%5Bcity_short%5D=%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F&insurant%5Bcity_kladr_id%5D=9100000700000&insurant%5Bstreet_kladr_id%5D=91000007000015600&insurant%5Bkladr_id%5D=9100000700001560079&insurant%5Bcity_okato_id%5D=35401000000&insurant_is_owner=1&owner%5Bur_name%5D=&owner%5Bur_inn%5D=&owner%5Bur_kpp%5D=&owner%5Bur_doc_ser%5D=&owner%5Bur_doc_num%5D=&owner%5BSurname%5D=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD&owner%5BName%5D=%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD&owner%5BPatronymic%5D=%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87&owner%5BBirthDate%5D=01-10-1984&owner%5BSex%5D=1&owner%5BSeria%5D=7508&owner%5BNumber%5D=225428&owner%5BDate_issue%5D=05-05-2008&owner%5BIssued%5D=%D0%A3%D0%A4%D0%9C%D0%A1&owner%5BAddress%5D=%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF+%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC%2C+%D0%B3+%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%2C+%D1%83%D0%BB+%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%2C+%D0%B4+137+&owner%5BZip%5D=295013&owner%5BState%5D=%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF+%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC&owner%5BRegion%5D=&owner%5BCity%5D=%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C&owner%5BStreet%5D=%D1%83%D0%BB+%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F&owner%5BHouse%5D=137&owner%5BBuilding%5D=&owner%5BApartment%5D=&owner%5Bfias_level%5D=8&owner%5Bcity_short%5D=%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F&owner%5Bstreet_kladr_id%5D=91000007000015600&owner%5Bstreet_kladr_id%5D=91000007000015600&owner%5Bcity_short%5D=%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F&owner%5Bcity_kladr_id%5D=9100000700000&owner%5Bstreet_kladr_id%5D=91000007000015600&owner%5Bkladr_id%5D=9100000700001560079&owner%5Bcity_okato_id%5D=35401000000&AgrISN=27169459\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"status_id\"\r\n\r\n172703\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--",



  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Postman-Token: f17bbf48-37e7-4a6a-afd2-d098e18ed751",
    "content-type: multipart/form-data"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

//print_r(curl_getinfo($curl));


curl_close($curl);



if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  print_r($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: У тебя в заголовках 2 контент тайпа - это нормально?

Comment: Убрал сперва один потом другой, результат тот же.

Comment: @Jean-Claude site.ru написан как пример.
Вообще должен быть https://

Comment: Воспользуйтесь curl_error и посмотрите свою ошибку (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-error.php)

Comment: @Дмитрий
Проверил, пишет что ошибок нет. У меня проблема конкретно в отправке данных.
Они как то не правильно доходят.
В целом мне надо отправить через form-data

`data=date_start=28-10-2018&Phone=%2B7(978)054-62-98&Email=webdizaine%40gmail.com&Transport%5BCategory_Nasko%5D=3366&Transport%5BMark_Nasko%5D=371531&Transport%5BModel_Nasko%5D=371591...`

Comment: а массивом просто данные нельзя передать?  http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php     Замечание:

    Передача массива в CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS закодирует данные в виде multipart/form-data, тогда как передача URL-кодированной строки закодирует данные в виде application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS рабоатет совместно с CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, удалите пустой CURLOPT_ENCODING, непонятно зачем CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST извращение (CURLOPT_POST)

Comment: @Jean-Claude огромное Спасибо, заработало)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте передать данные массивом, из официальной [справки](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php)

> **Замечание**: Передача массива в CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS закодирует данные в виде multipart/form-data, тогда как передача URL-кодированной строки закодирует данные в виде application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Также:

`CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS` работает совместно с `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`, удалите пустой `CURLOPT_ENCODING`, непонятно зачем `CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION`, `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` извращение (замените на `CURLOPT_POST`).